# remove single quotes from a json using node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have  a string like this

```
var record ={ '"test":"Connect_Disconnect","jobid": "65","os":"Windows NT","report":"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>"': '' }
```

From this I have to remove single quote

How is this possible using node.js?
I am tired of the fact that it is not working

```
record = record.replace(/"/g, "");
```

I want an output as below

```
{
  "test": "Connect_Disconnect",
  "jobid": "65",
  "os": "Windows NT",
  "report": "Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK<br>Add Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK<br>Connecting to Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Connected:OK<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:OK<br>Delete Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>"
};
```

Comment: Can you clarify which single-quote you are trying to remove? record is an object not a string, whose only key looks like a JSON string and doesn't, as far as I can see, contain a single-quote.

Comment: yes i want o remove single quotes inisde that josn string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
var record ={ '"test":"Connect_Disconnect","jobid": "65","os":"Windows NT","report":"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>"': '' }
for(var key in record) { // get your string from original json object
    break;
}
record = JSON.parse('{' + key + '}'); // parse string to new json object
```

Comment: +1 from me. Extracting JSON from an object with a `for` loop looks kinda weird to me. We should really know what is the OP up to.

Comment: also from this how can i get the values jobid and test

Comment: with record.test and record.jobid you can get them. you can also use record['test']

Answer (score 1):

The global [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON) object has a `parse` method that will produce the desired output. The reason why this isn't documented in the node.js [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html) is because it's part of the language.

```
var record = JSON.parse('{"test":"Connect_Disconnect","jobid": "65","os":"Windows NT","report":"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>"}');
```

(Note that `{}` were added to wrap the whole string).

Comment: am getting error `undefined:1

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
`